# best way to slice std::vector inside loop with dummy variable

Tags: c++, loops, stdvector

I have the general code structure that iterates over a vector of structs, does some operations to the structs and appends them to a new vector of structs.  I then sort the new vector of structs.

```
vec<myStruct> now
now.push_back(someStruct)

for (i = 0; i < end; i++){
  vec<myStruct> next;
  for (j = 0; j < now.size(); j++){
    for (k = 0; k < end_k; k++){
      myStruct anotherStruct = now[j];
      anotherStruct = somefunction(anotherStruct, k);
      next.push_back(anotherStruct);
    }
  }
  std::sort(next.begin(), next.end(), myComparitor);

  //return top_n structs from vec<myStruct>
  vec<myStruct> dummy;
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    dummy.push_back(next[i]);
  }
  now = dummy;
}
```

My problem is mainly with the last part where I create a dummy vector that takes the top-n structs:

```
  //return top_n structs from vec<myStruct>
  std::sort(next.begin(), next.end(), myComparitor);
  vec<myStruct> dummy;
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    dummy.push_back(next[i]);
  }
  now = dummy;
```

Is there a more effective way of slicing from a sorted vector?  More specifically, I am questioning the use of a dummy vector to store the top-n results.  For now, I would say that `std::sort` should be considered some general sorting algorithm (not taken literally).  Since top-n results are required, I could use a priority queue.  But the question about the dummy variable to store the intermediate results still holds.

Comment: Btw, why did you forget all `;`s?

Comment: Comments are written with `//` or `/* comment */` in C++

Comment: the same reason why I use abstract variables to represent undefined functions that convey what i am trying to do...context.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
// sort only first limit elements
std::partial_sort(next.begin(), next.begin() + limit, next.end(), myComparator);

// truncate
next.resize(limit);

// update now
now = std::move(next);
```

Comment: I am not trying to sort the first N elements.  I am trying to return the first N elements of a sorted vec.  So replace `std::partial_sort` with my original line then use your next two lines.

Comment: @user18764 have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort
It considers **all** elements in the specified range, but stops sorting once it can assure that the N smallest elements are at their final location namely at the front.